# How to switch a "split" comma to colons

Tags: javascript, split, window.location

I think I am missing something easy here.  I am trying to split the URL and then switch the commas to colons.  Is there an easy way to do this.

```
<div id="splitit"></div>

<script>
    var mySplitResult = window.location.href.split('/');
    document.getElementById('splitit').textContent = mySplitResult;
</script>
```

So the results of "mySplitResult" is value,value,value,value,value and I want value:value:value:value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mySplitResult` actually contains an array of strings.

```
window.location.href.split('/');
["http:", "", "stackoverflow.com", "questions", "30086262", "how-to-switch-a-split-comma-to-colons"]
```

Then `Array.prototype.toString` converts it to a comma delimited string.

Instead use `Array.prototype.join`

```
document.getElementById('splitit').textContent = window.location.href.split('/').join(':');
```

Comment: Quick add on question - how would I remove everything before (http,https,ftp,file, etc...)://?  That way my results would be stackoverflow.com:questions:30086262:how-to-switch-a-split-comma-to-colons

Comment: I came up with `document.getElementById('splitit').textContent = window.location.href.replace(/^.+\:\/\//,'').split('/').join(':');`

Comment: You could use `Array.prototype.splice` for example `window.location.href.split('/').splice(2).join(':')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var mySplitResult=window.location.href.split('/').join(':')
```

That is how I would do it.

Comment: Boom - Thanks for that.  I was way over thinking this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for replace

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```
var myReplaceResult = window.location.href.replace(/\//g, ':');
```

Comment: add the g flag, please

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var mySplitResult = window.location.href.split('/');
    document.getElementById('splitit').textContent = mySplitResult.replace(',' , ':');
</script>
```

---

Very simply, it will replace any `,` with a `:`

Answer (score -1):

The reason that "mySplitResult" is being set to a comma delimited string is due to the nature of some prototype methods hanging off of the Array type.  As of ECMA5, if an object contains a join() method it will be called, otherwise the toString() method will be invoked (see [Array.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString))

For the Array type there is a [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method that uses a comma as the default delimiter.  This explains why you are seeing "value,value,value", because join() is being called during the assignment of textContent to mySplitResult.

To achieve your desired results you would change your code to call the join() method explicitly and pass in the desired delimiter:

```
var mySplitResult = window.location.href.split('/');
document.getElementById('splitit').textContent = mySplitResult.join(':');
```